# Creating an object in a for loop, and trying to access it elsewhere

Tags: java, jcheckbox

I am trying to create a program to shuffle music. I have already gotten all the songs imported, and now I am trying to create a ``JCheckBox for each song. I have a for loop that creates these checkboxes, but I need a way to test if the box is checked. I am already using if(box.isSelected()), but need to discern which box, and need to access box outside the for loop.
Here is my code.
By the way, `songs` is an `ArrayList`.

```
public static void checkboxList() {
    ArrayList<JCheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String element : songs) {
        System.out.println("Reached checkbox thing");
        System.out.println(element);
        JCheckBox box = new JCheckBox(element);
        checkboxes.add(box);
        panel.add(box);
        frame.pack();
    }
    int loop = 0;
    while (loop == 0) {
        if (checkboxes.contains(box.isSelected())) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would make more sense to simply add an `ActionListener`, though if you prefer this way, you'll have to iterate over all checkboxes.

Comment: I got to agree with Paul here, I think what you really need is an ActionListener: [Linkage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by everyone you can add an event listener to identify the object which generated the event.

```
public class evttest implements ItemListener{

//Declared your arraylist checkboxes global. To access it in other part of code
static ArrayList<JCheckBox> checkboxes ;

public evttest(){

...

checkboxList();
//After calling checkboxesList() call add method to add itemlistener to each of them
this.add();
}


public static void checkboxList() {
checkboxes = new ArrayList<>();
JCheckBox box;

for (String element : songs) {
    System.out.println("Reached checkbox thing");
    System.out.println(element);
    box = new JCheckBox(element);

    checkboxes.add(box);
    panel.add(box);
    frame.pack();
}

frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
}

//this method adds ItemListener to all the 
//checkboxes you have in your ArrayList checkboxes
public void add(){
    for(JCheckBox cb : checkboxes){
        cb.addItemListener(this);
    }
}



@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

    //If the item is selected then do something
    if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){

        //cb is the checkbox on which your event occured.
        //You can then use cb to perform your required operation

        JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox)e.getSource();
        System.out.println("clicked item is: " + cb.getText());
    }
}

public static void main(String...args){
    new evttest();
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you, this all looks fine. The one issue I get is that the this.add() does not work, because I am calling it and checkboxList() in a static function. However, I need the function to be static. Any ideas?

Comment: If you get a chance, @bonney, could you try to answer my above question? I need to get my program finished soon.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. If your class name is Drivers, type     Drivers instance = new Drivers(); Then just do instance.add();

Answer (score 0):

If you need unique identifiers, why not create your own JCheckbox?

Something like:

```
 public class MyCheckBox extends JCheckBox {

 public MyCheckBox(paramOne, paramTwo, paramN) {
     super();    
    //do stuff with the unique identifiers 
 }

 //inherit all methods from super class
 @Override
 public boolean isSelected() {
     return super.isSelected();
 }

  //ETC...
 }
```